# Is the `in` part of the for-loop called on each iteration in Python?

Tags: python

I have code that looks like this

```
for Dtheta_1 in np.arange(Dtheta_1_min,Dtheta_2,Dtheta_1_step):
    // Do stuff
```

Is `np.arrange()` called on each iteration of the loop or is it called once?

Comment: It is called once.

Answer (score 2):

assuming that np.arange returns an iterable object, e.g. a List, then it is only called once.